# set parameters in EventInput in Dialogflow V2 API

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, chatbot, dialogflow-es

I desperatly try to set parameters in a

```
dialogflow.types.EventInput
```

in python.

This [doc](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/Shared.Types) says the parameters need to be of type `Struct`.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49416563/how-to-add-parameters-to-dialogflow-event-in-python?rq=1) that the parameters needs to be a google.protobuf.Struct.
But it does not work for me.

Is there another `Struct` type equivalent in python?

If i send the `EventInput` without parameters, the intent is detected correctly.

I tried this so far:

```
import dialogflow_v2 as dialogflow
session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()

session = session_client.session_path(project_id, session_id)
parameters = struct_pb2.Struct()
parameters['given-name'] = 'Jeff'
parameters['last-name'] = 'Bridges'

event_input = dialogflow.types.EventInput(         
    name='greetPerson',
    language_code='de',
    parameters=parameters)

query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(event=event_input)

response = session_client.detect_intent(
    session=session, query_input=query_input)
```

Anybody having experience with this usecase?

Things i also tried:

1. Pass a `class` named p yields:

   > Parameter to MergeFrom() must be instance of same class: expected
   >   Struct got p. for field EventInput.parameters
2. Pass a dict:

   ```
   parameters = {
       'given-name': 'Jeff',
       'last-name': 'Bridges'}
   ```

   yields:

   > Protocol message Struct has no "given-name" field.
3. Generate Struct with constructor:

   ```
   from google.protobuf.struct_pb2 import Struct, Value
   parameters = Struct(fields={
       'given-name':Value(string_value='Jeff'),
       'last-name':Value(string_value='Bidges')
   })
   ```

   yields sometimes:

   > Exception in thread ptvsd.stopping (most likely raised during
   >   interpreter shutdown):

[image: This is the parameter section if my intent]

/EventInput

Comment: Have you tried passing your parameters simply as a `dict`?

Comment: I tried that but does not work. I just added that info to my question.

Comment: There is a typo in your `dict`: `give-name` for `given-name`

Comment: thx, fixed it but still same error message..

Comment: How can i pass parameter for non event call in queryInput in android? @TVK

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how I did this:

```
import dialogflow
from google.protobuf import struct_pb2

session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()
session = session_client.session_path(project_id, session_id)

parameters = struct_pb2.Struct()
parameters["given-name"] = 'Jeff'
parameters["last-name"] = 'Bridges'

query_input = {
    'event': {
        "name": "greetPerson",
        "parameters": parameters,
        "language_code": "de"
    }
}

response = session_client.detect_intent(
    session=session,
    query_input=query_input)
```

**Note:**
In dialogflow console, you must give default values of parameters as `#even_name.parameter_name`.
In this case for parameter `given-name` it would be `#greetPerson.given-name` and for `last-name` it would be `#greetPerson.last-name`.

**Docs Reference:**
We are using [DetectIntent](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent), in which we are using [QueryInput](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent#queryinput), in which finally we are using [EvenInput](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/Shared.Types/EventInput)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow! Setting the deafault exactly as you mentioned did the magic!
Can you please let me know if there is some documentation, where I could have read about this requirement?

Comment: @TVK i too banged my head over this, tried different things, then searched for the exact documents and format which it is expecting and got it worked. i have added doc reference in the answer as well.

Comment: Thx i read all of these before, but they dont mention that a default value is required. Only doc mentioning sth like that i just found was https://dialogflow.com/docs/concepts/slot-filling#parameter_values_from_contexts

Comment: oh yes, about that i came to know when i was working on slot-filling with help of doc that you mentioned and `understanding slot-filling` video tutorial from [this course](https://www.udemy.com/bots-with-dialogflow/)

Comment: How can i pass parameter for non event call in queryInput in android? @sid8491

Answer (score 0):

Information in accepted answer is incorrect.

You don't have to provide default values.

You can reference event parameters directly in Value column of Parameters table.

> To reference an event parameter in the parameter table or a response,
>   use the following format: #event-name.parameter-name.

[dialogflow docs](https://dialogflow.com/docs/events/custom-events)

Therefore, putting #greetPerson.given-name in Value would be enough.