# Add Parameters to EventInput on QueryInput for DialogFlow Java API

Tags: java, android, protocol-buffers, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to set parameters inside my `EventInput` object, in order to send it inside my `QueryInput` and detect the Intent. I'm using DialogFlow V2Beta1 API for Java version `com.google.cloud:google-cloud-dialogflow:0.85.0-alpha`. I'm aware of the json expected format based on
[Custom Events](https://dialogflow.com/docs/events/custom-events) documentation, but all method available didn't work for me. Related question for other languages didn't awnser it either: [set parameters in EventInput in Dialogflow V2 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54197528/set-parameters-in-eventinput-in-dialogflow-v2-api). I'm losing something about protobuf pattern?
My parameters are the following:
[image]

I've already tried the below code, but it doesn't work, the response from server always asks "What is the location_user?", meaning that the parameter is missing. On DialogFlow V2 happens the same issue.

```
queryInput = QueryInput.newBuilder()
                        .setEvent(
                                EventInput.newBuilder()
                                        .setName("REVISION")
                                        .setParameters(
                                                Struct.newBuilder()
                                                        .putFields("location_user",
                                                                Value.newBuilder()
                                                                        .setStringValue("Campinas")
                                                                        .build())
                                                        .build()
                                        )
                                        .setLanguageCode(config.getLanguage()
                                        )
                        )
                        .build();
```

output json:

```
name: "REVISION"
parameters {
  fields {
    key: "location_user"
    value {
      string_value: "Campinas"
    }
  }
}
language_code: "pt-BR"
```

Comment: How to pass parameter without an event?

Comment: I also have the same question as Subin: how to pass a parameter in a QueryInput object when calling detectIntent()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems to be correct.
The problem is in your Intent configuration.

from [dialogflow docs](https://dialogflow.com/docs/events/custom-events):

> To reference an event parameter in the parameter table or a response,
>   use the following format: #event-name.parameter-name.

In your example: put #REVISION.location_user in Value column in Parameters table.

I've checked your code and it works, please find my Intent configuration below

[sample intent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cktOz.png)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but IMHO that's not the problem. When I try to detect my Intent, the response from server always asks "What is the location_user?", meaning that the parameter is missing.

Comment: As in edited answer - I've checked your code and it works.
I've attached screenshot of sample Intent configuration I've used.

Comment: How to pass parameter without an event? @MortFollower

Comment: @SubinBabu I think this is separate topic. More details about your case would be needed. Nevertheless, if you use IntentAPI you can just create new parameter in context when you call Dialogflow.